# Ruby on Rails 5 strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm having some troubles with a project I'm working on. Be warned I consider myself very much a beginner/novice at all this still :)

To keep things short and sweet, I'm using Rails & active admin to build up an admin interface where i can perform CRUD operations on my database models, which is all working great. However I recently decided I wanted to add another field to one of my models, a "description" field, so generated a migration, ran `rake db:migrate` and updated my list of allowed params in my controller & active admin resource.

My problem is data is not saved for this new "description" field - wether its via creating a new entry or updating an existing one. I can see the output in the terminal confirms it is being filtered out by strong params; returning `Unpermitted parameter: :Description` However i am under the impression i have set up my strong params correctly, so I'm unsure if i have set up my permit params properly or what else i can do.

Using Rails 5.1.0 & will post code below.

```
class CellsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def index
  end

  private

    def cell_params
      params.require(:cell).permit(:name, :description)
    end

end

#database schema for my cell model
  create_table "cells", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "Description"
  end

#Active Admin resource
ActiveAdmin.register Cell do

 permit_params :name, :description

end
```

Again, greatly appreciate any help as I'm sure I've overlooked something, happy to provide any other information that is required :)

Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like the `description` param is not accepted because the model only has a `Description` column (with a capitalised `D`).  To fix that, either change each `params.permit(:description)` to `params.permit(:Description)` or just rename the column inside a new migration:

```
def change
  rename_column :cells, :Description, :description
end
```

I recommend renaming the column as it will avoid any trouble with the column in the future.

Comment: Yep, definitely recommend using lowercase for all field names to avoid future trouble and confusion.

Comment: THANKYOU!! fixed it all perfectly :) Im still very new and sometimes struggle with some of the naming / capitalisation stuff, i really appreciate your help :)